# How to find the given string is a RSS feed or not

Tags: java, xml, regex, rss, feed

I have a string which takes both XML and HTML input from a data downloaded from the given Url. I want to check whether the downloaded string is an rss feed of a html document before parsing through SAXParser. How to find this?

For example

If I download a data from http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss the resulting string is a rss feed

If I download a data from http://edition.cnn.com/2014/06/19/opinion/iraq-neocons-wearing/index.html the resulting string is a html document.

I want to continue my process if only the string is an rss feed.

Answer (score 1):

RSS and HTML are both subsets of XML. So you can obtain your data as XML and validate it against RSS XSD. Like this.

```
URL schemaFile = new URL("http://europa.eu/rapid/conf/RSS20.xsd");
Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(YOUR_URL_HERE);
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
try {
  validator.validate(xmlFile);
  // at this line you can be sure it's RSS 2.0 stream
} catch (SAXException e) {
  // NOT RSS
}
```

If you want to check namely String, you can check it for typical rss structure, like  root element, required  element in . But I won't recommend it.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this without validation, since some of the feeds could be big in size as well and there could be invalid characters in XML which causes a exception as well. So I won't be able to differentiate if its a RSS feed with errors or just a HTML file.

Comment: I think it's the most precise way. You could try solution below the code, but I could think of cases, when all goes wrong. You could also check extension of link: usually for RSS it's ".rss" :)